# Sampling from distribution defined variationally

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo

Suppose I define a probability distribution $\mu\in\mathrm{Prob}(\Sigma)$ over some compact $\Sigma\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ using a variational problem:
$$
\mu:=\arg\min_{\mu\in\mathrm{Prob}(\Sigma)} F[\mu].
$$
Here, $F[\cdot]:\mathrm{Prob}(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is an energy functional on the space of probability distributions.  Feel free to put any reasonable regularity assumptions you want to on $F[\cdot]$.

**Is there a way to sample approximately from $\mu$ without explicitly solving the variational problem?**

---

For instance, consider the following inefficient and likely incorrect strategy:

1. Randomly generate a sample of $k$ points $p_1,\ldots,p_k\in\Sigma$ uniformly from $\Sigma$
2. Evaluate $f:=F[\sum_i \delta_{p_i}]$, where $\delta_x$ is a delta function centered at $x$.
3. With probability "proportional to" $f$ (e.g. after repeating this process a few times to get an idea of how $F[\cdot]$ behaves), return a uniformly random sample from $\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}$; otherwise return to step 1.

This algorithm obviously makes no sense, but hopefully you see what I'm after.  I could imagine for some class of $F$'s (uniformly Lipschitz?) and large enough $k$, a strategy like this could get a reasonable approximation.  Or maybe there's an MCMC interpretation?

Comment: This is a most interesting question! In the event $\Sigma$ is a finite set, you can always use some sort of simulated annealing algorithm to solve the optimisation problem but this is not answering the question.

Comment: Glad to hear it's interesting!  I'm always nervous to ask something completely ill-posed...  If you have any ideas or which to chat, please let me know --- I can think of quite a few applications of such an idea.